# JAXB unmarshalling only a deeply-nested subset of an XML file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

My application receives a very lengthy XML document, and I would like to use it to populate a Java object.

However, while there are tons of deeply-nested elements in the XML, I am only interested in a handful of them.  I am also only interested in going from XML-to-Java.  I do not need the capability of marshalling my Java object back into XML.

I would like to use JAXB for this if possible, since my application's dependencies already include Eclipselink MOXy anyway.  However, I'm not sure how to grab only a handful of deeply nested element values.  I looked at the `@XmlElementWrapper` annotation, and thought about using it to annotate my Java class fields like this:

```java
...
@XmlElementWrapper(name="LEVEL_1/SUBLEVEL_1/YET_ANOTHER_SUBLEVEL")
@XmlElement(name="STATUS")
private String statusCode;
...
```

However, I don't know if that `name` attribute is valid.  I don't get that far anyway... the compiler tells me that `@XmlElementWrapper` can only be used when the member variable is a Collection type.  Most of the fields I'm trying to pull are single values.

I tried skipping the `@XmlElementWrapper` annotation, and seeing if `@XmlElement` alone would understand XPath values:

```java
...
@XmlElement(name="LEVEL_1/SUBLEVEL_1/YET_ANOTHER_SUBLEVEL/STATUS")
private String statusCode;
...
```

While this doesn't cause a compile error, it doesn't work either.  At runtime, Eclipselink simply instantiates my object with a `null` in this field.

Is there something I am missing, or is what I'm trying to do even possible with JAXB at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) using the `@XmlPath` extension.

```
@XmlPath("LEVEL_1/SUBLEVEL_1/YET_ANOTHER_SUBLEVEL/STATUS/text()")
private String statusCode;
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html

Comment: Thanks!  You might want to edit this code snippet, though.  It turns out that the @XmlPath path annotation just accepts a path string... there is no "name=" prefix.

Comment: @StevePerkins - Nice catch, I have fixed the snippet.